# Black Areas on Remote Desktop - Dell WYSE

Tags: remote-desktop, terminal-server, rds

my issue is quite similar to this post:
[MSTSC: Black Areas on Remote Desktop](https://serverfault.com/questions/641255/mstsc-black-areas-on-remote-desktop)

We have multiple users with Dell WYSE 3040 thinclients having the issue of black squares appearing on their display while being connected to our Terminalserver.
I tried the given steps, but it didn't help.
Also there are no similar settings in the thinclients menu. I just tried the method of deleting the cache.

The devices are new and it happens almost on every one of them.
Also I changed the wires and everything, but I didn't find a solution yet.

Has anybody else experienced something like this?

Answer (score 1):

FYI: The problem was a DisplayPort bug in the recent and last version of ThinOS.
Downgrading to version 8.4 helped.
Dell isn't aware of the bug or denies it, hoewever there are some reliable sources that reported the bug and an update to the new Version doesn't fix the problem.